# Read Multiple Languages from Excel with Java

Tags: java, character-encoding, multilingual

I have an excel spreadsheet that I am trying to read in, which has 45 different languages, ranging from English, to Japanese, to Turkish, to Bavarian, and everything in between. I need write each of the cells into an XML file, which isn't a big deal. The issue I'm having is getting all the languages to print out properly, and I'm not sure what type of encoding I can use to cover all the different languages and have them print out properly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Declare the xml's encoding as `utf-8` or `utf-16`